# Htaccess rewrite rule out of root

Tags: .htaccess, document-root

I am trying to do a special rewrite rule.
Suppose **ROOT** as my hosting root.

I have domain.tld set as root on **ROOT**/folder

When I try this from a script running on the domain.tld root (which is **folder**):

```
RewriteRule sth/?$ ../file.php
```

It doesn't work, cause I am leaving the domain Root. But, since I am on the same hosting, shouldn't it work? Is there any alternative?  I once heard about symlinks, do they apply here?

Thanks for your wonderful attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since I am on the same hosting, shouldn't it work?

No, doesn't matter if you are on the hosting service. A site's *Document root* is the upper-most directory apache will ever be able to access for that site. So when you rewrite a URL to `../file.php`, apache can't traverse any higher than the document root. **There is very good reason for this** as it prevents people with dodgy morals from making apache access files that they're not supposed to see (e.g. `../../../../../../etc/passwd`)

The only thing you can do is put file.php in your document root somewhere, or create a script that includes it:

```
require ../file.php
```

or

```
include ../file.php
```

and then call that script in your rewrite rule.

Comment: Beautiful answer, you deserve a Christmas meal today. Thanks.